# launchmode and Intent.setFlag

Tags: android

What is the final behavior of starting an already existed Activity?

If I set the activity's launchmode to singletop while does not set the activity's flag,

or I set the activity's launchmode to standard while set the activity's flag to Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Find the answer.

The configuration in the code will be higher priority to that set in AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0):

As Android Doc says,

**Note: The behaviors that you specify for your activity with the launchMode attribute can be overridden by flags included with the intent that start your activity, as discussed in the next section.**

This may helps you.

Related link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManagingTasks